# Add Included Products restriction to WooCommerce admin coupons list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, coupon

Add a column of the 'Usage restrictions > Products' field on the admin coupon list in WooCommerce.

How can I show the products that are attached to the coupons in the 'Usage restrictions > Products' field on the admin coupon list in WooCommerce?

Comment: Your question has already been partially answered [In this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65653372/add-a-custom-column-to-woocommerce-admin-coupon-list)... You will need to make some little changes: the meta_key for "Usage restrictions > Products" field is `product_ids` and you can use `get_post_meta( $post_id, 'product_ids', true );` to get the string value (a comma separated string of product IDS), where the variable `$post_id` is the coupon post ID included in the 2nd hooked function.

Comment: Thank you @LoicTheAztec. I was able to work on your suggestions.